# jekyll - not processing files in subfolders

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm using Jekyll to make a simple static site.

When I have Jekyll HTML files on the root of my project (in the same folder as the _layouts folder & config file) they render perfectly and I can preview them on http://localhost:4000/welcome.html instantly.

I'm starting to get alot of files on the root and want to organize the dynamic files into folders.

So, when I move a file into a subfolder Jekyll stops updating it. I can see my previous edits ( from when it was on the root ) but if I make any edits, it doesn't update.

http://localhost:4000/mydirectory/welcome.html - returns a 404

Should I be editing the config file to check for these folders? Something like -

```
source: [mydirectory1,mydirectory2]
```

Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you've run jekyll --server to check this?

I just checked my directory settings and I don't have anything in config.yaml that tell it where to look. If you run jekyll --server from the directory where you are storing everything it just recursively looks through everything and processess it according to the rules it has for each file type.

Are you running jekyll --server from the right directory?

Comment: I've restarted the jekyll server this morning and it seems to work. Not sure if it was a server or not, but you pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks v much for your answer.

Comment: Just a point of clarification, Jekyll is a static site generator. What this means is that after each change you'll make you'll need to run the command 'Jekyll' from the root directory for changes to be made.

Comment: I've set 'auto' to true in my config now, so I don't need to worry about running the command each time.